# Insert partials dyanmically in view along with its data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partials

I have a view in which I need to insert form fields, into view.
Now these form fields I need to render come f from API request, which basically tells name of field and input type.
So not only I need to insert the template but also fill up  input properties basically `name` attribute.
I am thinking of loading into data into partials, but I am not sure how to load partials dynamically unlike use `ng-include`
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use directives.

You can attach your html template (I'm assuming this is what you mean by partials) to a directive as follows:

```
.directive('myFormField1', function() {
  return {
    template: '<label>{{ my_label }}<input></input></label>'
  };
});
```

Then, you can issue your request and bind the data to your scope:

```
$http.get('/myUrl').
  then(function(response) {
     $scope.reqData = response.data
  }
```

Finally, you use the request data to dynamically generate your form in the main template. Substitute your own variables and conditions as appropriate.

```
<form>
  <div myFormField1 ng-if="reqData.shouldShowField1 == true"></div>
  <div myFormField2 ng-repeat="item in reqData.repeatedData"></div>
</form>
```

This should point you in the right direction, though without knowing specifics I obviously can't give you a full answer.

Comment: @jazmit- If I am not wrong, shouldnt directive be declared as `myFormField2` rather than `myFormField1` and also `<div myFormField2>` be child of `<div myFormField1>`

Comment: I was positing that you might need several directives to accomplish what you want, one for each type of form section that you are generating.  I only showed an example for myFormField1, adding another called myFormField2 is straightforward.